# Docker says it is running but it isn't

Tags: macos, docker

Docker says it is running, but it clearly isn't.

Machine is OSX 10.15.4

```
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default
machine:file user$ ps aux | grep "docker"
user          56224   0.0  0.0  4258892    256 s006  R+    4:56PM   0:00.00 grep docker
machine:file user$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using docker with boot2docker. It means that docker will run inside a virtual machine instead of your local machin and explain why you don't see the process with "ps". As mention in the Boot2docker github project https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker, you should use docker desktop for mac.

Comment: I feel foolish and extremely grateful. Thank you very much.